# How to find $e$ when $p,q,d$ are given?

Tags: rsa

I have solved till here .....
$$n=p*q$$
$$n=5*11$$
$$\varphi(n)=(p-1)*(q-1)=4*10=40$$
Now, how to find $e$, when $d$ is given as $27$ and message for encryption is $\text{abcdefghij}$.
We have to take $a=1, b=2, c=3$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In this RSA setting, I am assuming encryption key is $e$ and decryption key is $d$. Relationship between encryption and decryption keys is that decryption key should be multiplicative inverse of encryption key in modulo $\phi(n)$ i.e. 
$$d=e^{-1} \mod \phi (n)$$
So that,
$$de≡1 \mod \phi(n)$$
So, our goal is to find out $e$ and we can find out this as follows:
$$e=d^{-1}\mod \phi(n)=27^{-1} \mod 40=3$$
You can verify this as follows:
$$27\times 3 \mod 40=81 \mod 40≡1$$
So, $e=3$.

Comment: sir can you please tell me  how to solve:      27^-1 mod 40

Comment: You can use Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find the multiplicative inverse of 27 in modulo 40. Please google "Extended Euclidean Algorithm" to find out how the algorithm works.